# MarkLogic+'Could not find the datahubConfig.json file'

Tags: java, authentication, tomcat, marklogic

I'm getting this java exception since MarkLogic Data Hub is not able to login to MarkLogic database on Windows Laptop set up.

From `c:\quickstart-tutorial\quickstart-tutorial\project`

Execute: `java -jar marklogic-data-hub-central-5.8.1.war`

And see then see:

> 2023-05-07 13:25:50.162 [main] ←[34mINFO ←[0;39m c.marklogic.hub.central.Application - Starting Application using Java 1.8.0_191 on DESKTOP-XXXXXX with PID 36920 (C:\quickstart-tutorial\quickstart-tutorial\project\marklogic-data-hub-central-5.8.1.war started by XXXXX in c:\quickstart-tutorial\quickstart-tutorial\project)

> 2023-05-07 13:25:50.165 [main] ←[34mINFO ←[0;39m c.marklogic.hub.central.Application - No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"

> 2023-05-07 13:25:51.942 [main] ←[34mINFO ←[0;39m o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]

> 2023-05-07 13:25:51.943 [main] ←[34mINFO ←[0;39m o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Starting service [Tomcat]

> 2023-05-07 13:25:51.946 [main] ←[34mINFO ←[0;39m o.a.catalina.core.StandardEngine - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]

> 2023-05-07 13:25:53.340 [main] ←[34mINFO ←[0;39m o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext

> 2023-05-07 13:25:53.634 [main] ←[34mINFO ←[0;39m com.marklogic.hub.central.HubCentral - Will connect to MarkLogic host: localhost

> 2023-05-07 13:25:53.635 [main] ←[34mINFO ←[0;39m com.marklogic.hub.central.HubCentral - Hub Central is available at port: 8080

> 2023-05-07 13:25:54.650 [main] ←[34mINFO ←[0;39m o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
> 2023-05-07 13:25:55.281 [main] ←[34mINFO ←[0;39m c.marklogic.hub.central.Application - Started Application in 5.533 seconds (JVM running for 5.971)

> 2023-05-07 13:26:01.161 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ←[34mINFO ←[0;39m o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'

> 2023-05-07 13:26:06.689 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] ←[34mINFO ←[0;39m com.marklogic.hub.impl.HubConfigImpl - Could not find the datahubConfig.json file. Logging the cause for the failure

> 2023-05-07 13:26:06.689 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] ←[34mINFO ←[0;39m com.marklogic.hub.impl.HubConfigImpl - java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:8010

> 2023-05-07 13:26:06.719 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] ←[34mINFO ←[0;39m c.m.a.DefaultAppConfigFactory - App host: localhost

> 2023-05-07 13:26:06.720 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] ←[34mINFO ←[0;39m c.m.a.DefaultAppConfigFactory - REST admin username: admin

> 2023-05-07 13:26:06.723 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] ←[34mINFO ←[0;39m c.m.a.DefaultAppConfigFactory - App Services username: admin

> 2023-05-07 13:26:06.729 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] ←[34mINFO ←[0;39m c.m.m.a.DefaultAdminConfigFactory - Admin interface host: localhost

> 2023-05-07 13:26:06.730 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] ←[34mINFO ←[0;39m c.m.m.a.DefaultAdminConfigFactory - Admin interface username: admin

> 2023-05-07 13:26:06.734 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] ←[34mINFO ←[0;39m c.m.mgmt.DefaultManageConfigFactory - Manage host: localhost

> 2023-05-07 13:26:06.739 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] ←[34mINFO ←[0;39m c.m.mgmt.DefaultManageConfigFactory - Manage username: admin

> 2023-05-07 13:26:06.739 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] ←[34mINFO ←[0;39m c.m.mgmt.DefaultManageConfigFactory - Manage user with security role: admin

> 2023-05-07 13:26:06.836 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] ←[34mINFO ←[0;39m com.marklogic.mgmt.ManageClient - Initializing ManageClient with manage config of: [ManageConfig host: localhost, port: 8002, username: admin, security username: admin]

> 2023-05-07 13:26:06.867 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] ←[34mINFO ←[0;39m com.marklogic.mgmt.ManageClient - Initializing ManageClient with manage config of: [ManageConfig host: localhost, port: 8002, username: admin, security username: admin]

> 2023-05-07 13:26:08.936 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] ←[1;31mERROR←[0;39m o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
> com.marklogic.client.MarkLogicIOException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:8010

This is fresh installation MarkLogic Data Hun 5.8.1, using java 1.8.0, Gradle 8.1.1 and MarkLogic DB 11.x on windows laptop 10. As try to login MarkLogic Data Hub localhost:8080, getting above exception with file

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am getting following error as try to start or invoke Admin web page of the MarkLogic DB server. 127.0.01:8001 - 403 Forbidden
SEC-NOADMIN: (err:FOER0000) User does not have admin-ui privilege.
in /MarkLogic/security.xqy, at 7110:7, in sec:check-admin() [1.0-ml]
in /MarkLogic/Admin/lib/status-check.xqy, at 24:1, in adlib:status-check() [1.0-ml]
in /, at 7:0 [1.0-ml]

Comment: (2.) Then for http://localhost:8000/qconsole/ option attempt I get message Access to localhost is denied (3.) Only I am able to use monitoring Monitoring option (is working) Regards

Comment: Were you able to make it work as I am also getting the same error.